# Grouping table view sections by day and country

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios4

I have an Core Data entity called **Event** and the two relevant attributes are called **startDateTime** and **countryCode**. My problem is that the sections in my table view need to be grouped by day AND country code. I've seen a lot of examples on how the achieve grouping by day only (DateSectionTitles by Apple for example), but it gets a lot more complicated when I add the country code.

I use a transient sectionIdentifier as recommended in the DateSectionTitles example and the sections look something like this: "20110928 SE", "20110929 SE", "20110928 GB" etc.

I first tried this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDateTime" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"countryCode" ascending:NO];
sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
[sortDescriptor1 release];
[sortDescriptor2 release];
```

But this doesn't work since startDateTime has a time component which leads to index mismatch. What I need is to sort the startDateTime without the time component.

The obvious solution would be to separate the date and time into two different entity attributes. But when I think about it that wouldn't work since a date is relative to a timezone. When the phone changes timezone the date and times attributes would be invalid.

I've also tried to subclass a NSSortDescriptor and create a custom compareObject function, but it never seems to be called and I can't find any working examples.

How would you solve this? Is the subclassed NSSortDescriptor the way to go, or is there perhaps a much smarter way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a category on NSDate with a method that strips the time from the date returning just the day e.g. converts this:

```
2011-09-29 09:53:28 -0500
```

… to this:

```
2011-09-29
```

Then set your sort key to `dateAttribute.methodName`.

Comment: Hm didn't know I could use a dot like that. I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you very much TechZen! Will upvote when my reputation allows it.